# Creating Individual Matrix based on Label Matrix from DataMatrix

Tags: matlab

Let **label** be a matrix of size **N x 1** (type double) and **data** be a matrix of size **N x M** (type double). The entries in the **Label** matrix looks like **[ 1; 23; 135; ....; 6]** which conveys that the

First row in the **data** matrix belongs to label 1
Second row in the **data** matrix belongs to label 2 and label 3
Third row in the **data** matrix belongs to label 1, label 3 and label 5 and so on

I would like to create a cell array say **Individual{i}** which stores all those rows from the **data** matrix which belongs to label **i** as given by the **label** matrix.

The resultant **Individual{i}** matrix will be size **N_i x M**.

Is there any efficient way to do the thing rather than looping row by row of **data** and **label** matrix?

Comment: What is N(i)? In the first line of your question, N is a scalar... by the end you're indexing it like an array. I assume it should be the number of digits in Label(i)? Can you make your question a bit more precise? Do you have to use this strange indexing in Label, or can you change it?

Comment: I have edited the statement. **N_i** is nothing but the number of rows in **data** matrix having label **i**.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn your matrix `label` into a Boolean matrix L:

```
L = [ 1 0 0 0 0 0 ;
      0 1 1 0 0 0 ;
      1 0 1 0 1 0 ;
    ...
      0 0 0 0 0 1 ];
```

for your example. You can use a sparse matrix if N or the number of labels is very large.

Then I think what you call `N_i` is `sum(L(:, i))` and `L' * data` would compute the sum of all the rows in `data` with label `L`.

What do you want to do with the `data` once it's reached the `Individual` cell array? There's almost certainly a better way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Given the correct variables: `N, M, data, label` as you described, here's a sample code that creates the desired cell array `Individual`:

```
%# convert labels to binary-encoded format (as suggested by @Tom)
maxLabels = 9;                            %# maximum label number possible
L = false(N,maxLabels);
for i=1:N
    %# extract digits of label
    digits = sscanf(num2str(label(i)),'%1d');

    %# all digits should be valid label indices
    %assert( all(digits>=1) && all(digits<=maxLabels) );

    %# mark this row as belong to designated labels
    L(i,digits) = true;
end

%# distribute data rows according to labels
individual = cell(maxLabels,1);
for i=1:maxLabels
    individual{i} = data(L(:,i),:);
end
```